# "Prettifying" the custom options in cart page

Tags: checkout, cart, custom-options

I am setting up a store and the client realized the way the custom options are displayed on the cart are "stupid" and I cannot for the life of me get them to change.

Here is an image of what I hope to accomplish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/myU1l.jpg the top one shows how it is currently being displayed. the bottom part is how I want it to be displayed. there is no individual styling, they are all encapsulated with a single `<dd>` tag.

```
<dl class="item-options">
    <dt>Adobe:</dt>
        <dd>
            Adobe Acrobat XI - Professional - $427.00, Adobe Acrobat XI - Standard - $149.00, Adobe Captivate 8 - $949.00
        </dd>
 </dl>
```

I'm using mageworx. com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html to make a template for custom options, so i do not need to add them by hand each time, and it has an option to put linked SKUS's in the cart but it just puts a jumble of products into the cart, if a client buys 2 computers with different software, there is no way for us to know which software goes on which computer.

I have been suggested to style it using CSS, which is impossible, (being they are contained inside a DD tag)

I have also been suggested to str_replace the ","'s with `</li><li>` which outputs the following: imgur.c om/dSOMQwG.jpg as you can see in that example, only the first item has the , replaced, the rest are nested list items. I do not understand why magento feels the need to place them in one block of text.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a third party extension. Please contact the developer directly for support.